# Single-row subquery returns more than one row - Real solution

Tags: sql, oracle

I'll be very fast.

**Problem:** My subquery is returning more than one row (and this is ok, because it should returns more than one, or just one), and trigger the ora error 1427, closing the query results.

**Question:** How can I show all the registers of this subquery?

**Notes**

- All my searches on internet says that you can limit by 1, but this is not what I really want.
- D table is like a matrix, I give FIELD4 with a specific value, that returns FIELD to me. And in the same query, I have another value to FIELD4, and returns another type and business result on FIELD.

---

```
 SELECT (SELECT B.Value
                FROM TABLE_B B
             WHERE B.FIELD1 = A.FIELD1
                 AND B.FIEL2 = A.FIELD2
                 AND B.FIELD3 = A.FIELD3
                 AND B.Category= 'Adress') AS RESULT_FIELD,
         (SELECT B.Value
                FROM TABLE_B B
             WHERE B.FIELD1 = A.FIELD1
                 AND B.FIEL2 = A.FIELD2
                 AND B.FIELD3 = A.FIELD3
                 AND B.Category= 'Gender') AS RESULT_FIELD2
FROM TABLE_A A;
```

### **Tables example:**

```
Table A   

ID   Name      Age    
1    Lapras     6    
2    Lincon     45


Table B    

ID   A_ID    Category      Value    
1      1       Gender      Female    
2      2       Gender      Male    
3      1       Adress      Avenue one    
4      1       Adress      Avenue Two    
5      2       Adress      Avenue Eleven
```

---

As you can see, It has more than one register on B, and I need to show on the result table all Adresses, considering the condicional that I pass on Category colunm.

Code updated*

The result should be like:

```
ID Name    Age Gender   Adress 
1  Lapras  6   Female   Avenue one
1  Lapras  6   Female   Avenue two
2  Lincon  45  Male     Avenue eleven
```

Comment: Your query (which by your own admission doesn't do what you want) is of no help in understanding your requirement. Please show a small, made-up sample of your input tables, a sample of your output (by hand if you can't do it otherwise), and the logic to get from one to the other. Then showing your attempt at a solution is always important (and according to the forum rules, possibly required), with an explanation of what isn't working. You already covered this last part perfectly, but not the first part(s). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting your desired results (per your example input/output) requires `JOIN` to be used, plus some logic for the multiple categories.  Here is one possible example using the two categories you referenced (`gender` and `adress`):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Name, A.Age, B1.Value as Gender, B2.Value as Address
FROM TABLE_A A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B B1 ON B1.A_ID = A.ID AND B1.Category = 'Gender'
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B B2 ON B2.A_ID = A.ID AND B2.Category = 'Adress';
```

Notice that you end up with the Cartesian product of Category values.  For example, if someone had two values entered for the first category (maybe not for Gender but another one) and two values for the second one, you would get 4 results back - a result for each permutation (2 categories x 2 values in each category).  Even so, this style of query seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you use a subquery?  This is a simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT B.FIELD as RESULT_FIELD
FROM TABLE_A A JOIN
     TABLE_B B
     ON B.FIELD1 = A.FIELD1 AND
        B.FIEL2 = A.FIELD2 AND
        B.FIELD3 = A.FIELD3 AND
        B.FIELD4 = 'SOMETHING';
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mentioned that the D table is like a matrix, I give FIELD4 with a specific value, that returns FIELD to me. And in the same query, I have another value to FIELD4, and returns another type and business result on FIELD. I don't know if this info is relevant or the solutions is simple as you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Your query is returning N results for N records in your base table (TABLE_A).  A subquery cannot be used to create additional rows - which means for each row of TABLE_A, the subquery **must** return a **single** value for each of the N rows in the base table.  Maybe we're misunderstanding the results you are looking for - could you provide some sample input and the expected output?  For each row in TABLE_A, do you want all the matching values from your "matrix" (TABLE_B) to be spread out in multiple columns, or what?